# How to import data from GCS to Vertica native table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, vertica

I want to import the data from Google cloud storage to Vertica's native(managed) table. I have imported data from google cloud storage but it is coming in external table. I have gone through [this link](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/NewFeatures/9.2/9.2.0/LoadingData.htm) but it only showing using external table and I want to import the data in managed table in Vertica.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the table in internal Vertica ROS (Read Optimized Store) format, all you have to do is to create the table and then insert into the new table the rows from the external table:

So - get the external's table definition:

```
SQL>select export_objects('','conc_ext',false)                                                                                                                                                                
export_objects

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE public.conc_ext
(
    ts timestamp,
    request_type varchar(12),
    concurrency int
)
 AS 
copy from '/home/gessnerm/1/Vertica/bmw/conc.csv' delimiter '|' skip 1;
```

And create your own internal table, same schema, new name, using the output above and removing the `EXTERNAL` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE public.conc_ros                                                                                                                                                                                  
(
    ts timestamp,
    request_type varchar(12),
    concurrency int
);
```

And, finally:

```
INSERT /*+DIRECT */ INTO public.conc_ros SELECT * FROM public.conc_ext;
```

That should be it.

Of course, there will be a lot of possibilities to improve performance by optimising the physical design, as your auto, default, projection for the new ROS table won't be an optimal design...